# On the statistical occupancy of energy levels for a Boltzmann distribution at high temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, statistics

Suppose we have a two-level thermodynamical system:
[image]

In what follows, we will adopt the following convention: $E_a=0$, $E_b=\cal E$.
For a system of $N$ classical (non-interacting) particles, the mean total energy is $U=N\langle E\,\rangle$, where $\langle E\rangle$ is the expected value of the energy of each particle, which is given by
$$
\langle E\rangle = \sum_{i}E_i\,p_i  
$$
as prescribed by statistics. In our case $i=a,b$ while $p_i=p(E_i)$ follows the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution:
$$
p(E_i)=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{E_i}{k_BT}\right)}{Z}, \qquad Z=\sum_i \exp\left(-\frac{E_i}{k_BT}\right)
$$

It's easy to see that
$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}U(T)=\frac{N\cal{E}}{2}
$$
meaning at high temperature half of the particles are expected to be found on the "excited" state $E_b$, and half of them of the "ground" state $E_a$.

Mathematically, this is the right result, but... *why* does this have to be like this? Intuitively, I expected *all* the particles on the excited state.

My professor said "no, this can only be the case with negative temperatures", making this whole concept even more obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particles in the environment have, on average, energy of about $k_{\textrm{B}}T$.  If $k_{\textrm{B}}T \gg \mathcal{E}$, the two internal states of the system are essentially degenerate, as far as the environment is concerned.  In other words, it costs essentially no energy (relative to $k_{\textrm{B}}T$) for the system to change state.  Therefore, in each "collision" of a particle in the environment with a particle in the system, the outcome of the collision is essentially random: the system particle will be in either of its internal states with equal probability.